# How to make a string in python start a function

Tags: python

If I have a function lets say:

```
def func1():
    print "HELLO"
```

How do I call the function using a raw input?

```
command = raw_input("Enter: ")
```

if the user enters `func1` how do I call the function with this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary for map between function names and function calls:

```
d = {
    "func1" : func1
}

d[command]() # will execute func1 function if command == "func1"
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DisPNAME you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Use `globals()` or `locals()` if method is defined in the same module:

```
def func1():
    print("HELLO")

globals()[input("Enter: ")]()
# or locals()[input("Enter: ")]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval()` as well, but beware, this will execute any code it is passed. If you let that choice do the user of the program for you, you open up doors to all kind of malicious things someone could do with this backdoor...;)

anyway, here's how it would look like:

```
command = raw_input("Enter: ") 
result = eval(command)

#or plainly eval(command) if you do not wish to store the return value in a variable
```

if the user enters `func1()` in the prompt, it will be executed later by the `eval()`-function.

Comment: Especially very dangerous using with `raw_input()`.

Comment: yep. but nontheless a valid way to get what the OP asked....just not advisable to use :-)